# How to deploy metabase using Laravel Forge

Tags: digital-ocean, forge, metabase

I would like to deploy [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) using [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/)
Has anyone tried this before? Kindly provide tutorial

I can SSH into my digital ocean server (which is connected to forge), to create directory and download metabase. But I am not able to complete the process. Forge already has nginx and should be an easier setup